# Two circles tangent to x-axis at $(4,0)$ and tangent to the line $4x - 3y = 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Determine the distance between the center of the first circle and the second circle !.

It is known that the gradient of the line is $\dfrac 43$. However, it is hard to find the centers for both circles using the available informations.

Comment: do you see that a smaller circle in the upper half plane and a bigger circle in the lower half plane? it will be good to draw a picture. i don't know how to put figures here but i drew one on a paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the equation of any circle touching x axis be $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ where $r>0$

As the circle passes through $(4,0);$  $(4-a)^2+(0-b)^2=r^2$

So, the equation becomes $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=(4-a)^2+b^2$

Now the distance from the center to any tangent = radius

So, $\sqrt{(4-a)^2+b^2}=|b|\implies a=4$

So, the equation becomes $(x-4)^2+(y-b)^2=b^2$

Finally, for the tangent $4x-3y=0,$

$\sqrt{(4-4)^2+b^2}=\dfrac{|3\cdot4-4\cdot b|}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}$

$\iff5|b|=|12-4b|$

Square both sides to find the two values of $b, b_1,b_2$(say)

So, we need $|b_2-b_1|$

Comment: how do you get |b| for the radius then you can obtain a = 4 ?

Comment: I think you should dot-product with $(4,-3)/5$ instead of $(3,-4)/5$

Comment: @wawar05, Do you still have any confusion?

Comment: no, thank you mate...

Answer (score 1):

$(2+i)^2=3+4i$ so the line that bisects the angle at the origin has slope 1/2.  The other line has slope -2.  So the centres are at $(4,2)$ and $(4,-8)$.

Comment: The question's tagged "precalculus", "geometry". Suing complex numbers may be too advanced for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

the distance between the centers is $10$.

here is a way to do this. let the acute angle between the line $y = {4 \over 3}x$ and the $x$-axis be $2t$ then we know from the slope $\tan(2t) = {4 \over 3}$ we will need the tangent of $t$ we will use the double angle formula $\tan(2t) = {4 \over 3} = {2\tan t \over 1 + \tan^2 t}$ by solving the quadratic equation, we find $$\tan t  = {1 \over 2}.$$

remember the line $$y = {4 \over 3}x  \text{ and } y = 0$$ are two tangents drawn from the origin so that the line connecting the centers of the circle bisect the angles between the lines. you have two right angle triangles with angle $t$ in one the adjacent side is $4$ and the other opposite is $4$. smaller radius is $4 \tan t = 2$ and the larger radius is ${4 \over \tan t } = 8$ so the sum of the radii is 10 and is the distance between the centers.